# iTunes Connect bundle id issue

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode7

Before submitting final version of my app on Appstore I was testing whether in build submission is there issue or not and I did it successfully. Now I have app my in "Prepare For Submission" state on iTunes with some bundle id string say "com.abc.def". But the problem is that I will have to upload my final version using my client's credentials not using my own. So now if I use same bundle id "com.abc.def" and upload my build will there be any issue? I tried to delete existing version but it says that I should have atleast 1 approved version of my app only then I will be able to delete it. During Prepare for Submission I cannot delete my app. Please help me with this issue.

[image]

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The AppID (bundle) is declared in Apple Developer Portal not iTunes Connect. Try deleting it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolve such issue you simply need to follow this steps :

- First you need to remove it from your Account. If you are not able to remove it no worry. Keep it as it is.
- Here Note that even if you will not remove it from your account, you still can use & create same bundle Id from clients Account & upload app

**Important:**

- If you have used name in your account that you want on iTunes that would not be used now from clients App. So in that case you have to create slightly different App Name.

Hope it will guide you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to itunes connect from your acount.

Go to app details.

Go to pricing and availability.

Now remove the app from sale.

Now you can delete the app from your account.

Now you can add this as a new app from your client account.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: My app is not in ready for sale state its in Prepare for Submission. So I don't have any option to delete it from anywhere.

Comment: I know.. read my answer and follow step by step.. If you still can't, you can share your account details with me and I will do it for you. You can change your password later

Comment: Updated my question with options inside pricing and availability.

Comment: I think you will have to click on the "Choose" button to select availability first and then do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you cannot delete app when it is in Waitting for Review State**

1. If you submit app to App Store with same bundle id "com.abc.def", It would not be any issue for approval. It may be approved and ready for sale.
2. Remember that bundle id always represent organizationName and your app name. **I strongly recommend don't do that** (don't upload with wrong build id). Because in future **client may raise any query**.
Instead of that, change bundle identifier. Make new entry for this app with same name and new bundle id on iTunes connect. Then submit for approval.
Your are not required to remove the app with wrong bundle id. Instead you may use it to practice skills like how to register for in app purchase and other stuff that require app on iTunes
.

Comment: "com.abc.def" is just for reference only otherwise this is not my actual bundle id. Thanks for your reply I will keep these points in my mind.